# Blackberry browser cache issue

Tags: php, caching, browser, blackberry, blackberry-playbook

i had developed a program in PHP which plays video in Blackberry browser using jwplayer. Everything works fine but while playing video greater than 150 MB with video length 144 second, the videos stop playing after few seconds, just buffering icon is shown.

I think the cache of the browser is full. so it cant cache the data.

It stops working in about 80-100 MB or data is played.

Any opinion will be appreciable.

thanks in advance

Comment: I would definitely suggest compressing the video more or lowering the quality some. A 2:24 video at 150MB is incredibly large.

Comment: @jprofiitt thanks for comment but video is uploaded by viewers, not by admin we don't have control in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the problem is related to the particular device software version or the device model. Have you tried to reproduce the issue on another device and/or devices with different/newer/older device software?

I think the best solution will be to re-encode uploaded videos as YouTube does. When a user uploads a video to the server run your process to re-encode the video using strict and working quality parameters.